# how to check large no. of urls in a txt file for proxy response and capture output in txt file in windows?

Tags: powershell, proxy, response

I do not want to end up opening 13k URLs and to check wether each one them is successfully blocked by proxy or not. End result is to capture in a single line in a text file with appropriate delimiter

Comment: appropriate delimiter URL_Name Proxy_Response and Proxy_Block_Category

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any sort of script running for it at the moment?
Using powershell you could read in the url from text files, call each url and check status, then write to file.

Sample code: I dont have a proxy server to test on so its not guaranteed to work

```
$urls = Get-Content C:\data\urls.txt

foreach($url in $urls){
$webReq = [net.WebRequest]::Create("$url")
$status = $webReq.GetResponse().Statuscode()

#this will return the status code i.e. '200', '500'. '404'
#according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error
# Error 523 is Proxy Declined request error
# Print url and status code to file
echo "$url $status" >> c:\data\response.txt
}
```